# PHP/MySQL: Match content of one table with another and print that instead

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have 2 tables, `bs_reservations` and `bs_events`. The first contains a bunch of IDs, the second both the (same) IDs and the corresponding titles. I'm trying to replace on-the-fly the IDs taken from first table with the corresponding titles, taken from the second table.

First table is `bs_reservations` which only has an `eventID` column. Here's the PHP code I use to fetch the IDs:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "blabla";
$password = "blabla";
$dbname = "blabla";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM bs_reservations WHERE serviceID=3";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) { echo "<table><tr><th>Name</th></tr>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>" . $row["eventID"]. "</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

The second table, `bs_events` has 2 columns, `id` and `title`. `id` corresponds to the same `eventID` of the first table, `title` is the corresponding title.

How can I modify the snippet above to match `eventID` from the first table with `id` of the second table and replace on-the-fly `$row["eventID"]` with the corresponding `title`?

Don't say to just use the second table as of course the first table has also other columns I'm fetching.

Comment: What is `serviceID` if it's not in either of your tables?

Comment: In this case it is in both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `JOIN` directive in your query:

```
$sql = "SELECT *
        FROM `bs_reservations`
        JOIN `bs_events` ON `bs_reservations`.`eventID` = `bs_events`.`id`
        WHERE `bs_reservations`.`serviceID`=3";
```

You can then access the `title` attribute of each row just as if it was in the same table:

```
echo "<tr><td>" . $row["title"]. "</td></tr>";
```

---

**Update**:

If you need the events with no reservations yet as well, you can use a `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`:

```
$sql = "SELECT *
        FROM `bs_reservations`
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN `bs_events` ON `bs_reservations`.`eventID` = `bs_events`.`id`
        WHERE `bs_reservations`.`serviceID`=3";
```

Comment: It's strange! If I use that query the results are fewer!
Here's the original code: https://istitutoviadellecarine.gov.it/test/ids.php
Here's with titles (your addition): https://istitutoviadellecarine.gov.it/test/titles.php EDIT: it's ok that

Comment: It's a `JOIN` - if data does not have a matching value in the table being joined, the row won't show up in your results. You might have events with no reservations yet, correct? That would account for the slimmed results.

Comment: Yep. But since I'm fetching "main" results from `bs_reservations` (which contains the reservation) joined table `bs_events` CERTAINLY has those IDs of the events booked.. Here's more clear maybe (contains all the data, don't worry are fake info). First table: https://istitutoviadellecarine.gov.it/test/listadocenti.php, joined tables https://istitutoviadellecarine.gov.it/test/listadocenti2.php

Comment: You are misunderstanding how a `JOIN` (specifically an `INNER JOIN`) works. If you need the events that don't have any reservations yet, you can use `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` - I've updated my answer with this alternate solution. For these events with no existing reservations, there will be one record with the event info from the `bs_events` table, but `NULL` values in place of the `bs_reservations` data.

Comment: Nope. JOIN and RIGHT OUTER JOIN give me the same results.
I'm fetching directly the reservations table! It's not possible to have less results after I JOIN the events table as events table contains all events ID. reservations table instead contains only event ids of booked ids.

Comment: Results should be fewer if I fetched events first and then joined reservations. But I'm doing the opposite!

Answer (score 0):

Use a join in your query.

```
SELECT r.*, e.title FROM bs_reservations as r JOIN bs_events as e on r.event_id = e.id WHERE r.serviceID = 3
```

Then in your loop you can echo the title. Assuming the reservations table doesn't have a title column, then you may want to rename it `..., e.title as eventTitle FROM ...`

```
echo "<tr><td>" . $row["title"]. "</td></tr>";
```